# What's the difference between AddScoped and AddSingleton in .net core Console Application?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, console-application

The scope of an `AddScoped` in an ASP.NET context is understood, i.e., at the request level. When it comes to a console application, it does not have a request context, right? How will it behave?

`services.AddScoped<SomeServiceClass>();`
`services.AddSingleton<SomeServiceClass>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> at the request level. When it comes to a console application, it do not have a request context, right?

Yes, in ASP.NET Core framework will create as scope per request. In console application there is no "request" concept out of the box but you can create scopes manually when needed (which can be beneficial when you have some iterative and/or long running processing for example involving EF Core `DbContext`'s):

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
// services.Add...
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

while (some_condition)
{
    using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();

    var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISomeService>();
    service.DoSomething();
}
```

The main difference that with scope validation enabled scoped services can't be resolved from the root scope (this is done to prevent negative effects similar to ones "introduced" by [captive dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#captive-dependency)):

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
// services.Add...
services.AddScoped<object>();
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider(new ServiceProviderOptions
{
    ValidateScopes = true, // can be detrimental for perf, disable on Prod
    // ValidateOnBuild = true
});

// InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'System.Object' from root provider:
var service = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<object>();
```

From the [.NET dependency injection: Service lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes) doc:

> **Scoped**
>
> - For web applications, a scoped lifetime indicates that services are created once per client request (connection). Register scoped services with AddScoped.
> - In apps that process requests, scoped services are disposed at the end of the request.
> - When using Entity Framework Core, the AddDbContext extension method registers DbContext types with a scoped lifetime by default.

> **Singleton**
> Singleton lifetime services are created either:
>
> - The first time they're requested.
> - By the developer, when providing an implementation instance directly to the container.
>
> Every subsequent request of the service implementation from the dependency injection container uses the same instance.
>
> Singleton services must be thread safe and are often used in stateless services.
>
> In apps that process requests, singleton services are disposed when the `ServiceProvider` is disposed on application shutdown. Because memory is not released until the app is shut down, consider memory use with a singleton service.

Comment: So If I do not create new scope explicitly, how it will behave? Transient or singleton?

Comment: @SubinJacob it depends on the settings. If you have validation enabled (which I recommend for non-production environments) - it will throw an exception. Otherwise it will be one dependency per scope, hence one since you will have only root scope.

Comment: This is what I got from ChatGPT " the services are registered as scoped, but they are effectively behaving like transient services. In other words, every time you request a scoped service without creating a scope, a new instance of the service is created". But when I try in code, it behaves like a singleton scope.

Comment: @SubinJacob  _"This is what I got from ChatGPT"_ - and you think this is correct exactly why?) _"it behaves like a singleton scope"_ - yes, as I wrote.

Comment: @SubinJacob again, if you don't create a scope you still have one - the root one, and you can have only one scoped dependency per scope making it basically a singleton if you are using only root scope.

Answer (score 5):

In a console application there is no built-in concept of a request like there is in a web context. So, if you use dependency injection (DI) in a console application, you have to manually manage the scope of your services.

```
    using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SomeServiceClass>();
    // use service here
}
```

The singleton will behave the same though

Answer (score 1):

Even though this differs from web application's dependency injection. Concepts remain the same.

AddScoped:

- service is created once per scope. In the context of a web application, this typically means once per HTTP request.
- In a console application nature, a scope might relate to a specific operation.

AddSingleton:

- service is created only once and reused for the lifetime of the application
- In a console application, this means the service is created when it
  is first requested and reused for the entire duration of the
  application.

> Read more on dependency injection via Official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-8.0#service-lifetimes)